# usr/bin/ld : cannot find -l<DynamicLibraryName>

Tags: c++, makefile

I am beginner in c++ and I started learning this language by doing the game snake in cpp..

I don't understand the error occurred when I compile..

I have this makefile which build a dynamic library

```
CC=g++
CFLAG= -fPIC -Wall -Wpedantic

DIR_OBJ=Objet_de_librairie
DIR_LIB=Librairie
DIR_SRC=Source_librairie

NAME_LIB=OpenGlSharedLib
LIB_SO=$(NAME_LIB).so


.PHONY=all


all: CREATE_DIR CREATE_OBJET CREATE_LIB

CREATE_DIR:
    @mkdir -p $(DIR_LIB)
    @mkdir -p $(DIR_OBJ)

CREATE_OBJET:
    @$(CC) $(CFLAG) -c $(DIR_SRC)/$(NAME_LIB).cpp -o $(DIR_OBJ)/$(NAME_LIB).o

CREATE_LIB: $(DIR_OBJ)/$(NAME_LIB).o
    @$(CC) -shared $(DIR_OBJ)/$(NAME_LIB).o -o $(DIR_LIB)/$(LIB_SO)

clean:
    @rm -r $(DIR_LIB)
    @rm -r $(DIR_OBJ)
```

this makefile is launch by another makefile with the command

```
COMPILE_LIB:
    $(MAKE) -C $(LIB)
```

And finally build the output with the rule :

```
$(OUTPUT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -L/home/schweppes/Documents/Projets/snake/Lib/Librairie -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(OUTPUT) -lOpenGlSharedLib -ldl
```

I took care to export

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/schweppes/Documents/Projets/snake/Lib/Librairie
```

witch contains library OpenGlSharedLib.so

But I don't understand why I get the error

```
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -lOpenGlSharedLib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**ne peut trouver -lOpenGlSharedLib** means **cannot find -lOpenGlSharedLib **

Does someone already got this fail?

Comment: What is `-lOpenGlSharedLib`, how have you got it? Do you mean `-lGL`?

Comment: `-lXXX` normally looks for `libXXX.so`

Comment: -lOpenGlSharedLib is an dynamic library currently save like OpenGlSharedLib.so. I am trying to link this dynamic lib that I have created to the program.

Comment: Ok my bad, I forgot the prefix **lib** while creating the dynamic lib. Thanks guys !!